# Why do none of the links to images or PDF files work? They show the broken link icon

Tags: software

In reference to the patent: [US20150105592](https://www.google.com/patents/US20150105592)

Comment: Use the Espacenet link on the Google Patents page. It will take you to the [original document](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?NR=2015105592A1&FT=D&CC=US).

Answer (score 1):

I think that is a server error on Google's end. However, you can go here:
http://www.freepatentsonline.com/20150105592.pdf
and that site will show the original filling application with photos and descriptions.